# How to sort dictionary of list based on certain column?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I have a table like below, stored in a dictionary:

[image]

The dictionary looks like this

```
d = {
'A': ['45', '70', '5', '88', '93', '79', '87', '69'], 
'B': ['99', '18', '91', '3', '92', '2', '67', '15'], 
'C': ['199200128', '889172415', '221388292', '199200128', '889172415', '889172415', '199200128', '221388292'], 
'D': ['10:27:05', '07:10:29', '17:04:48', '10:25:42', '07:11:18', '07:11:37', '10:38:11', '17:08:55'], 
'E': ['73', '6', '95', '21', '29', '15', '99', '9']
}
```

I'd like to sort the dictionary based on the hours from lowest to highest and sum the columns A, B and E corresponding the same value in column C as in image below (where sums of A, B and E are in red):

[image]

Then, the resulting dictionary would look like this:

```
{
'A': ['70', '93', '79', '242', '88', '45', '133', '87', '5', '69', '161'], 
'B': ['18', '92', '2', '112', '3', '99', '102', '67', '91', '15', '173'], 
'C': ['889172415', '889172415', '889172415', '', '199200128', '199200128', '', '199200128', '221388292', '221388292', ''], 
'D': ['07:10:29', '07:11:18', '07:11:37', '', '10:25:42', '10:27:05', '', '10:38:11', '17:04:48', '17:08:55', ''], 
'E': ['6', '29', '15', '50', '21', '73', '94', '99', '95', '9', '203']
}
```

I currently try to sort the input dictionary with this code, but doesn´t seem to work for me.

```py
>>> sorted(d.items(), key=lambda e: e[1][4])
[
('D', ['10:27:05', '07:10:29', '17:04:48', '10:25:42', '07:11:18', '07:11:37', '10:38:11', '17:08:55']), 
('E', ['73', '6', '95', '21', '29', '15', '99', '9']), 
('C', ['199200128', '889172415', '221388292', '199200128', '889172415', '889172415', '199200128', '221388292']), 
('B', ['99', '18', '91', '3', '92', '2', '67', '15']), 
('A', ['45', '70', '5', '88', '93', '79', '87', '69'])
]
>>>
```

May someone give some help with this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you allow to use pandas to solve this task ?
If yes, then you can transform your data to

```
pd.DataFrame
```

object

```
data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary, orient = 'columns')
data = data.sort_values(by =„D”)
```

And then return to dictionary again using

```
_dict = data.to_dict()
```

Comment: Thanks s3nh for your answer. I've tried and the sorting it works, but when I do ` pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary)` it generates a column with indexes and when sorting, that column is unsorted (`data.to_dict()`). Is there a way to avoid generated that index column, since I see more complex to sum de values desired having that extra column.

Comment: I just update answer by adding ```orient = 'columns'``` argument.

Comment: Still the same output. Thanks for the help anyway.